# Cross-process locking with Android NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, locking, mutex

Is there a way to lock e.g. using mutexes or file locks on Android NDK, across processes?

I want to lock a socket so only one process can send to it at once. The processes are not forked, they are independent invocations.

As I am writing a shared library, I cannot rely on any shared location which requires permissions to write to it, neither can I use any process local storage, because this would be unable to share with other processes by definition. This goes for app names too. I'm essentially looking for something like abstract namespaces with AF_UNIX sockets, but for mutex/semaphores.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the processes have the same user ID, you can use `flock(2)` to lock a file (could be anything accessible to both processes), or the POSIX semaphore operations (`sem_open(3)`) to use a semaphore.

If the user IDs are different, the mechanisms will still work, but you have to set the file permissions to be more "open" -- which introduces the risk of some malicious app performing a denial-of-service attack by grabbing the lock.

Comment: Unsure if they will have the same user ID, but will give this and semaphores a try. I'm hearing that neither is supported cross-process in Android which is my concern.

Comment: `flock()` is a standard UNIX mechanism that works cross-process.  IIRC, SysV semaphores (`semctl()`) aren't supported by the NDK, but POSIX semaphores (`sem_open()`) are and will also work.  (I'll add a couple notes to the answer.)

Comment: For sem_open they need to be named semaphores in order to work cross process right? Is there a reliable way to name a semaphore on android? I remember having to use abstract namespaces to get an AF_UNIX socket, but I don't think there is such a thing as abstract namespaces for semaphores.

Comment: Also for flock, there is no place on the android filesystem that is guaranteed to be writable by ALL apps, regardless of permissions. Hence the use of abstract namespaces for AF_UNIX sockets. I find it strange that we can do inter process comms with sockets, but not inter process locks on android...

Comment: Thanks by the way, not trying to be difficult! Just making sure I haven't missed something

Comment: Files on external storage (e.g. `/sdcard`) are accessible to all.  This allows sharing, but raises the risk of interference from malicious apps.  For semaphores, use the four-argument `sem_open()` that takes a name and a mode.  You can use unnamed semaphores (`sem_init()`) in a shared-memory segment if you have one, otherwise you have to use named.  Include your app package name in your semaphore name to avoid conflicts with other apps.

Comment: I think the app requires permission to write to `/sdcard`, something along the lines of `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` which rules this out. I should mention I am writing a shared library which means I can neither affect nor rely on the permission settings of an app which loads it.

Comment: Be aware, sem_open(3) does not implemented in [android native](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/pthreads/+/master/sem_open.c).