# Android Native Semaphore Not implemented

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk

When using native semaphores (semaphore.h) on android i faced with this error :

`Error : Function not implemented`

My native code :

`sem_t *sem = sem_open(name , O_CREAT | O_EXCL , 0666 , value);`

i think this error is related to `rt` library, is there any way to link `librt` to toolchain ?

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270113/how-do-i-stop-sem-open-failing-with-enosys

Comment: i use semaphores in android ( elinux ) not in linux kernel base os - is there any way or another header to use semaphores on android ? or i only can use pthread mutex , cond vars for android native synchronization ?

Comment: According to a comment on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18606519/8513665 , Android does not implement `sem_open(3)` (hence the ENOSYS).  Nor does it apparently support `SysV semaphores`.  Another comment on that answer mentions using an unnamed semaphore (with `sem_init`) in shared memory, so maybe that'll work.

Comment: thank's , using pthread mutexes solved my problem